# c++: OpenCV cv::Mat::at cannot assign to a variable that is const

Tags: c++, opencv

A class definition in the vein of,

```
class T {
    public:
        Mat D;
        void operator()(double &p, const int * pos) const {
            D.at<double>(pos[0]*2 + 1, 1) = p;
        }
        T(Mat D);
};
```

results in a compilation error, *'cv::Mat::at': you cannot assign to a variable that is const*. The constructor simply assigns **D** as the argument.

Moving **D** to a global scope fixes the error but that is of course not preferred. This leads me to two questions:

1. What is the source of the error and can it be resolved?
2. Is there a better way to pass a variable into the scope of a Functor?

For the second point it should be noted for clarity that the functor will be used inside `Mat::forEach<double>`, so passing additional variables as arguments is not an option.

Comment: Hold the `Mat` `D` by reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void operator()(double &p, const int * pos) const
```

is a `const` function.  That means inside the function body, all class members are treated as if they were declared as `const`.  Since you want to mutate `D` you have a few options, you can remove the `const`, you can declare `D` as `mutable` so it can be modified, or you could make `D` a reference member like

```
class T {
    public:
        Mat& D;
        void operator()(double &p, const int * pos) const {
            D.at<double>(pos[0]*2 + 1, 1) = p;
        }
        T(Mat& D) : D(D);
};
```

This works because the reference is marked as `const` (which means nothing since references can't be reassigned), not what it refers to.